# Openssl unresolved external BN_is_zero

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, openssl

During the development of a small project using statically linked OpenSSL 1.0.2e I encountered a strange error in VS13:

```
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _BN_is_zero
```

Quite often, this happens when you forget to properly liked `.lib` file in the project properties, but all of the properties were double-checked - they are correct.

Configuration - `Release`, `MT`, [libs](http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/) are `MT`, `bh.h` included.

And even if one of the libraries is not linked properly, I should have multiple compiler errors complaining about unresolved external symbols of all the elements used in the project, but in my case unresolved external symbol is the only `BN_is_zero`.

After quick googling there wasn't found any issues, related to openssl bugs and I guess that the problem resides at my project.

Any tips will be appreciated.

**UPD**

Here is some screens:

[image: additional linker dependencies]

[image: error list]

Comment: The linker may stop on the first unresolved symbol, I'm not sure. It may help to post a screenshot showing where you're including the OpenSSL library in the linker settings.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually forked the csrp github project and compiled it against the particular openssl libraries you are pointing at. I had to slightly modify test_srp.c and src.c to add some code that isn't available on VS2013. A fork of csrp with the changes applied and the visual studio project for VS2013 to compile it can be found here:

https://github.com/sigmoidal/csrp

Note that you need to change the paths of the openssl path on *BOTH* the debug and release versions to reflect your VS Configuration Properties:

- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

  ```
   D:\dev\openssl\openssl-1.0.2e-vs2013\include
  ```

  (you should not point it to $openssl_path/include/openssl, it will not work)

and also:

- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies:

  - For release configuration:

    ```
    D:\dev\openssl\openssl-1.0.2e-vs2013\lib\libeay32MT.lib
    D:\dev\openssl\openssl-1.0.2e-vs2013\lib\ssleay32MT.lib
    ```
  - For debug configuration:

    ```
    D:\dev\openssl\openssl-1.0.2e-vs2013\lib\libeay32MTd.lib
    D:\dev\openssl\openssl-1.0.2e-vs2013\lib\ssleay32MTd.lib
    ```

  (notice the "d" suffix on debug libs)

Compiled ok for me.

Comment: grabbed some code from your repo and it fails in runtime. Have no time to debug it myself.

Comment: the project works fine, the problem is that the code you pointed us to, the test_srp.c has code that does not compile in VS2013. I replaced the test_srp.c code that requires modification with the one shown in the Usage Example of the github project and recompiled and run it without a problem against OpenSSL 1.0.2e. Please note that you are doing a horrible mistake taking a bn.h from an older version and using it to compile with a different library. #defines may take unexpected values that can lead to serious problems.

Comment: maybe you're right. I'll carefully compare results from my and your solution

Comment: there is no need to compare anything, just download the github again (i updated the fine containing main) and compile, it works fine, no runtime crashes. make sure you are using debug/release correctly. works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but according to the OpenSSL source `BN_is_zero` is defined as a macro:

http://osxr.org/openssl/source/crypto/bn/bn.h#0407

So perhaps the module that is compiled into `srp.obj` is making a call to `BN_is_zero` but is not including `bn/bn.h` and in the absence of a prototype the compiler is generating a default one.

If this is the case, including the `bn.h` definitions should avoid the linker error.

Comment: <openssl/bn.h> is allready included. or you meant some other bn.h?

Comment: That's the `bn.h` I meant. Can you see the call to `BN_is_zero` in the  source code for `srp.obj`? Is `srp.obj` your code? Does it have all the necessary #include directives?

Comment: Yep, it has all the includes needed. Generally I'm trying to build this project https://github.com/cocagne/csrp so you can see it yourself - everything needed is included.

Answer (score 0):

It was tricky, but I've finally solved it based on the Drew MacInnis tips.
The matter is that openssl 1.0.2e broke the `BN_is_zero` functionality by simply removing the macros-containing header from sources. So, the solution is:

1. Download the bn.h include file from `1.0.1h` (or [here](https://gist.github.com/im-infamou5/bb50ba17b45191605e00))
2. Place bn.h to `%OPENSSL_HOME%/crypto/bn` directory
3. Change `#include <openssl/bn.h>` for `#include <../crypto/bn/bn.h>`

Comment: And yet you don't even upvote Drew. You could also have updated his answer with your solution. And, if you post an answer, you should also accept it.